# How can I configure 2 video cards to use on 3 monitors?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors

How can I configure 2 video card and 3 monitor to use? I am using 11.10 x64. One of the cards is a `GF8600GTS` and the other is a `GF8400GS`.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

i dont think this is possible, since the processing of graphics has to be done by one of them only. This is how most motherboards are architectured... unless your MB allows double Bus for video processing. Had that same issue when trying to connect 3 monitors to windows xp, some months ago.

Comment: check this out, and read the FIRST rule: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Dual-Video-Cards